# Wordpress - get current user details

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm trying to write a function that is called when a new user registers that emails the admin with information about the new users account.

I am trying to do this with the `get_currentuserinfo();` function but have been having no luck. Below is the code I am currently using:

```
// WooCommerce New Customer Admin Notification Email
function new_customer_registered_send_email_admin() {
    //variables
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $useremail = $current_user->user_email;
    $username = $current_user->user_login;
    $firstname = $current_user->user_firstname;
    $lastname = $current_user->user_lastname;

    wp_mail( 'email@domain.com', 'test', 'The user ' . $user_login .' created an account on the website. Email: ' . $useremail . ' );
}
add_action('new_customer_registered', 'new_customer_registered_send_email_admin');
```

Whilst the email comes through without an issue, the variables aren't printing.

Comment: try to use print_r($current_user) and see what it display for user_login user-firstname etc etc then you can easily use the nicename or name anything you want.

Comment: @imranqasim where should I use that as it's obviously in an email...Or do you mean to use `print_r()` in the `wp_mail()` function?

Comment: sorry i forgott to mention when you are working on a development phase then you must know how to debug your code first as you see you are getting an array of objects named $current_user then you must find a way to print them out to debug purpose just before wp_mail function use print_r($current_user) then exit(); function and when you will run your program you will see object shown by the $current_user object and from here you can choose proper field names you wanna use for wp_mail

Comment: Running `print_r($current_user)` doesn't display anything...

Comment: if the user hasn't set up his/her first and last name then u must use user_nicename if first_name and last_name returns empty.

Comment: also this function get_currentuserinfo() is deprecated so better use wp_get_current_user() function to be more secure and updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following code and run it I'm sure you are testing it on the local server, not on live server otherwise print_r will display all the user info including emails password etc so you must try this on the local machine.

```
     function new_customer_registered_send_email_admin() {
//variables
global $current_user;
wp_get_current_user();
$useremail = $current_user->user_email;
$username = $current_user->user_login;
$firstname = $current_user->user_firstname;
$lastname = $current_user->user_lastname;

   print_r($current_user);exit;
   }
 add_action('wp_login', 'new_customer_registered_send_email_admin');
```

i'm sure this code will help you to debug what exactly you are looking for.

Thank You!

Comment: I have now identified the right variables that I know are right because I printed the contents however when put into the email, nothing prints out still!

Comment: I've checked it and confirm that it's working for me and I can echo out user_nicename, user_email, user_login without any problem.